# Word field code can't calculate date less than 17 days out

Tags: microsoft-word, date, field-codes

I grabbed a bit of code to add in Word to calculate a date X days out from today's date:

```
{QUOTE
{SET Delay 17}
{SET a{=INT((14-{DATE \@ M})/12)}}
{SET b{={DATE \@ yyyy}+4800-a}}
{SET c{={DATE \@ M}+12*a-3}}
{SET d{DATE \@ d}}
{SET jd{=d+INT((153*c+2)/5)+365*b+INT(b/4)-INT(b/100)+INT(b/400)-32045+Delay}}
{SET e{=INT((4*(jd+32044)+3)/146097)}}
{SET f{=jd+32044-INT(146097*e/4)}} 
{SET g{=INT((4*f+3)/1461)}}
{SET h{=f-INT(1461*g/4)}}
{SET i{=INT((5*h+2)/153)}}
{SET dd{=h-INT((153*i+2)/5)+1}}
{SET mm{=i+3-12*INT(i/10)}}
{SET yy{=100*e+g-4800+INT(i/10)}}
"{dd}-{mm}-{yy}" \@ "MMMM d, yyyy”}
```

The code works fine, except when the delay is between 6 and 16 days. So today, December 27, 2021, a delay of 5 days yields January 1, 2022, but a delay of 6 days yields February 6, 2022. Likewise, a delay of 16 days yields December 1, 2022, while a delay of 17 days yields January 13, 2022.

Unfortunately, I went looking for this code specifically to generate a field that calculates 14 days out, so this bit of code is quite impressive but ultimately useless.

Can anyone help me figure out how to get this thing to kick out the correct dates?

Answer (score 0):

The definitive reference for Date calculations in Fields was written some time ago by Word MVP Paul Edstein. I recommend downloading his [Date Calculation Tutorial](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38719-microsoft-word-date-calculation-tutorial.html). Be sure to review the introductory material. His field for this is on page 8 of the tutorial. *(Use only after reading the introductory material!)*

> {QUOTE{SET Delay 14}{SET a{=INT((14-{DATE @ M})/12)}}{SET b{={DATE
> @ yyyy}+4800-a}}{SET c{={DATE @ M}+12*a-3}}{SET d{DATE @ d}}{SET
> jd{=d+INT((153*c+2)/5)+365*b+INT(b/4)-INT(b/100)+INT(b/400)-32045+Delay}}{SET
> e{=INT((4*(jd+32044)+3)/146097)}}{SET
> f{=jd+32044-INT(146097*e/4)}}{SET g{=INT((4*f+3)/1461)}}{SET
> h{=f-INT(1461*g/4)}}{SET i{=INT((5*h+2)/153)}}{SET
> dd{=h-INT((153*i+2)/5)+1}}{SET mm{=i+3-12*INT(i/10)}}{SET
> yy{=100*e+g-4800+INT(i/10)}}"{mm}-{dd}-{yy}" @ "dddd, d MMMM yyyy"}

Paul's fields have worked for thousands of users for decades. The tutorial is a Word document that you can download. You can directly copy the working field into your documents.

Here is [my page on date calculations](http://addbalance.com/word/datefields2.htm). It shows the following:

> { QUOTE "{ SET " Delay" "14" } {  SET "DaysInMonth" { IF { CreateDate
> @ "MM" } <> 2 {  = ROUND(30.575*{ CreateDate @ "MM" },0)-
> ROUND(30.575*{ = { CreateDate @ "MM" } -1 },0) } {  IF {  = MOD( {
> CreateDate @"yy" } , 4 ) } > 0 "28" "29" } } } { SET "NextMonth" {
> IF {  CreateDate @ "MM" } = 12 "1/97"  "{ = {  CreateDate @ "MM" } +
> 1 }/97 } } {  IF {   = {  REF "Delay" } + { CreateDate @ "dd" } } <=
> { REF"DaysInMonth" } { CreateDate @ "MMMM { = {  REF "Delay" } + {
> CreateDate @ "dd" } }, yyyy"}{ QUOTE { NextMonth @ "MMMM" }  { = {
> REF "Delay" } + { CreateDate @ "dd" } - { REF"DaysInMonth" } },  { IF
> { CreateDate @ "MM" } <> 12 { CreateDate @ "yyyy" } { CreateDate @
> "{ = 1 + { CreateDate @ "yyyy" } # "xxxx" }" } } } }" }

When working with fields posted on the Internet, I use the [Add-In from Word MVP Graham Mayor to convert field codes to text and back](http://www.gmayor.com/export_field.htm).

Here is [my article on the Microsoft website on Dealing with Fields in Word](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501). It has additional resource links.